# Why are a few hats still on?

Tags: support, winter-bash, profile-picture

Despite the closing of the Winter Bash last week, there are still a few hats on the profile pictures of some users. Is it a bug?

Comment: Do you have an example​? It's possible they took a screenshot and used it as their avatar. What happens when you right click on the avatar, is the hat still there?

Comment: @Jenayah - that’s a possibility, I didn’t think about that.

Comment: @Jenayah - I am using an iPhone so I can’t really tell. https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers

Comment: @user070221 The link you posted doesn't have a hat anymore :-)

Answer (score 18):

On [the profile you provided](https://web.archive.org/web/20190107054023/https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers)<sup>1</sup>, right clicking on the avatar and selecting "Open image in new tab" returns what seems to be a screenshot:

> [image: waffles hat on avatar]

My guess is that every such profile you will encounter will have used a screenshot of their hats (or edited one on their avatar).

When Winter Bash was still here, hats weren't part of the avatar, but were a SVG layer added upon them.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This is an Internet Archive screenshot of said profile when it still had the "hat", while Winter Bash had ended. Said user has now gone back to their "usual" avatar (see comments).</sub>

Comment: Ooops! I forgot to change back to my original avatar after the holiday period. But I blame the SE techies for not supporting the wearing of multiple hats. As you correctly guessed, I "cheated" with a modified screenshot - because I wanted to wear the waffle as a kind of "Nightmare before Christmas", ***as well as*** wearing a pair of cool shades! :)

Comment: ...Dammit! - Turns out the original jpg isn't actually on the PC I'm using at the moment, so it'll have to wait until I move to my other machine later. Prolly time to update the "ephemeral comments" in my profile anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20160806001407im_/https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/59ec10af93c80b961ed1f53faef3bc66?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG)?

Comment: Oh. How are you able to do that? I assume you haven't hacked my other PC, 'cos even if you could do that, *it's not currently turned on!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers for the record, unless it's completely unplugged, I _think_ someone with the right skills could still do some nasty stuff to a supposedly "dormant" PC. Me, I just fed your profile link to the [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20180801000000*/https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers) :)

Comment: I don't kid myself. We've already ceded the very *notion* of "personal privacy" to the likes of Amazon, Apple, Facebook, Google,... And once lost, personal freedoms are rarely recovered, imho.

Comment: I still sport my owl face years after it has been recollected from everyone else...

Answer (score 8):

It's totally because they manually made it still appear there, also, the person you linked removed his hat around seven hours ago, but there are actually other examples:

1. [Vickel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/251777/vickel):

[image: 1]

2. [Stephen Rauch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/347908/stephen-rauch):

[image: 2]

Comment: I fell in love with my rubber ducky hat so I decided to wear it for a little while longer... :)

Comment: @Vickel Lol, :-), looks much better than regular i think, lol, :D

Comment: the regular avatar is a cool catch I made from an oceanfront chapel in my town, which has history back into ancient times. Its shape is hexagonal, an exception in Portuguese architecture...

Comment: @Vickel Wow, sounds cool, :-)

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capela_de_S%C3%A3o_Sebasti%C3%A3o_(Ericeira), this is in PT didn't find it in EN, but just put it into a translator